# what does this c snippet do?

Tags: c, algorithm

```
// input, output, i, and k are uint16_t type
// It is assured that k is non-negative and "small enough"
// k = 4
// input = 0x3a44
output = 0;
for (i=k; i<16; i++){
if (input & 1<<i)
output = output | 1 <<(i-k);
}
```

so input = 0011 1010 0100 0100
with k = 4 or 0000 0000 0000 0100 the loop runs 12 times

I guess what is confusing me is how the if and output parts are working, I know the bitwise operators & and | and that left shift is <<..but I get lost with what the overall function of the loop is

Comment: Extremely narrow interest on your extremely narrow interest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's apparently intended to make the output equal to (16 bits of) the input, right-shifted 4 bits (or whatever the value assigned to K happens to be).

Comment: Knowing this, what would you say is the purpose of doing this through iteration? Could it just be demonstrating the operation one bit at a time?

Comment: @JohnP: I'd guess the reason was because it was what happened to occur to the author.

Comment: Thanks to the phrasing of the comment, I was able to find the source. http://www.cs.colostate.edu/~cs270/.Spring12/schedule.shtml -> http://www.cs.colostate.edu/~cs270/.Spring12/Assignments/PA4/NewPA4.pdf -- CS 270, 'More Assembly Programming
Loops and Conditionals'. I believe it was designed to introduce the constraint on `k` so that students have to experiment with the effect of out-of-bounds values, and the behavior within bounds was just supposed to be something recognizable. (Control structures were 7 weeks earlier, maybe this was prep/review before learning about traps.)

Answer (score 2):

If the `i`th bit in `input` is set, then the `i-k`th bit in the output will be set, for `i` ranging from `k` to 15. The value of `output | (1 << n)` is what you get by taking `output` and setting the `n`th bit to 1, since `1 << n` is an integer which has only one bit, namely the one in position `n`, set to 1.

Answer (score 0):

This is a logical shift k bits to the right. Not sure why `output = input >> k;` is not used, but I am no C expert

Comment: This may be a snippet of a larger C sample, as opposed to a snippet containing all of the context. This would explain the unused variable, and its use would help explain the motivation of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

When trying to understand dense code like that, try writing a table of values out on paper, and manually calculate each item from the loop.

Or, if you're comfortable in Excel, build it as a spreadsheet.  You can have one row per iteration of the loop, and that row can refer to the previous row if necessary (as you'd have to with the variable `output`).  By unrolling the loop, and showing intermediate values (like what `(1<<i)` and `1<<(i-k)` are), you can get a better idea of what's happening.